# calculation gives me NaN

Tags: matlab, statistics, regression, logistic-regression

I am trying to implement multinomial logistic regression using gradient descent, but my cost function starts assigning `NaN` values to the weights. Can somebody plz tell what am I doing wrong?

```
function [ cost ] = costFunctionMultiNominal( inputX,resultY,weights )
%UNTITLED8 Calculates the cost for gradient descent,assumes inputX has one
%additional feature for constant and Weights is a classes X features matrix

[rows,cols] = size(inputX);
numOfClasses = size(weights,1);
summation = 0;
for i=1:rows
    classLevelSummation = 0;
    for j=1:numOfClasses
        if resultY(i)==j
            denominatorSum = 0;
            for l=1:numOfClasses
                denominatorSum = denominatorSum + exp((inputX(i,:)*weights(l,:)')-4444);
            end
           **classLevelSummation = classLevelSummation +  log(exp(inputX(i,:)*weights(j,:)'-4444)/denominatorSum);**
        end
    end
    summation = summation + classLevelSummation;
end
cost = summation/(-rows);
end
```

Here is the weight updating function:

```
function [ Weights ] =
  getWeightsUsingGradientDescentMultiNominal(trainingX,resultY,iterMax,Alpha,weight0,lambda )

%Returns updated weights through gradient descent,weight0 are the intial randomized weights 
%   Detailed explanation goes here

rows = size(trainingX,1);
cols = size(trainingX,2)+1;
Weights = weight0;
numOfClasses = size(Weights,1);
%Adding one's to the input data for the constant terms
a = ones(rows,1);
X = [a trainingX];
%Each column corresponds to one weight, updating weights column wise:
%Also plot cst function simultaneously
tempCost = 0;
display(costFunctionMultiNominal(X,resultY,Weights));
plot(1,costFunctionMultiNominal(X,resultY,Weights),'r');
hold on;
for n=1:iterMax
    %Have to do this for all classes, i.e rows in weigths
    for j = 1:numOfClasses
        %First Calculating the Sigma over rows for all X
        summation = zeros(1,cols);
        for i=1:rows
            p = -1 * calculatePofJMultiNominal(X(i,:),Weights,j);
            if resultY(i) == j
                p = 1 + p;
            end 
            summation = summation + X(i,:)*p;

        end
       Weights(j,:) = Weights(j,:) - (Alpha)*(summation/(-rows) + lambda*Weights(j,:));
    end
    cost = costFunctionMultiNominal(X,resultY,Weights);
    display(cost);
    costDiff = tempCost - cost;
    if i~=0 && abs(costDiff)/cost <= 0.0001
        display('Breaking because of cost very less!');
        break;
    end
    tempCost = cost;

    plot(i,cost,'r');
end
hold off;
end
```

As far as I understand, the `NaN` is coming because of the large numbers in exponential terms. I tried reducing a large number from the exponential (-4444) but to no avail.

I tried dbstop if NaN and that tells me it stops in the cost function at line(bold in the code above) :

```
classLevelSummation = classLevelSummation +  log(exp(inputX(i,:)*weights(j,:)'-4444)/denominatorSum);
```

classLevelSummation becomes NaN even if I remove the large constant value -4444

Comment: `DBSTOP IF NANINF` may help you in finding out exactly where the NaN is coming from.

Comment: Tried that, plz check the update

Answer (score 0):

In `log( exp(blah) / denominator )` it's unnecessary to exponentiate and then take the log—these two operations undo each other, and it could be that the `exp()` call is exceeding the floating point range. You can re-write this without an `exp` if you remember that   `log( A / B )` is equal to `log(A) - log(B)`.

A simple overflow in `exp` will likely give you an Inf rather than a NaN, however.   You should check the value of `denominatorSum` because that also stems from an exponential term.

Comment: Yes,the denominatorSum is the term that becomes Inf, because after first iteration weights become larger. I have no idea though that why is this happening. I am trying to follow this: http://blog.datumbox.com/machine-learning-tutorial-the-multinomial-logistic-regression-softmax-regression/